# Mean and variance of a Beta distribution with $\alpha \ge 1$ or $\beta \ge 1$?

Tags: beta-distribution

What conditions must satisfy the mean and variance of a Beta distribution so that the parameters $\alpha,\beta$ are not both less than 1?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "distribution to be convex." You probably need to restrict the convexity to the support of the distribution function (for otherwise *no* distribution function is convex). But are you referring to its density function, cumulative density, or perhaps something else?

Comment: @whuber See edit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I have taken the liberty of correcting your definition by inserting the word "segment".  Otherwise (in the form originally stated) your definition would not hold for any distribution.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105029/alpha-beta-ge-1-in-a-beta-distribution-what-does-it-imply-for-the-mean-and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters of a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution with mean $0\lt m\lt 1$ and variance $0\lt v\lt m(1-m)$ are

$$\alpha = m\frac{m(1-m)- v}{v},\quad \beta = (1-m)\frac{m(1-m)-v}{v}.$$

[image: Figure 1]

*This shaded contour plot of $\alpha$ has contours ranging from $0$ (at the top of the colored region) to $1$ (along the bottom).  The plot of $\beta$ is its mirror image.*

If they are not both less than $1$, then algebra shows us that

$$v \le m\max\left(\frac{m(1-m)}{1+m}, \frac{(1-m)^2}{2-m}\right).$$

[image: Figure]

*The valid set of all possible means and variances of Beta distributions is contained beneath the gray curve.  Within that set, those where one or both of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $1$ or greater is shown in darker blue.  These tend to have lower variances on the whole.*

Answer (score 2):

The mean of the Beta distribution is

$$\mu = \frac {\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$$

We want to see whether restricting the permissible range of $\mu$, will guarantee that we will have either $\{\alpha \geq 1, \beta >0\}$, OR $\{\alpha >0, \beta \geq 1\}$.

Treating the mean as a function of the parameters we obtain

$$\frac {\partial \mu}{\partial \alpha} > 0, \;\; \frac {\partial \mu}{\partial \beta} <0$$

So it is monotonically increasing in $\alpha$ and monotonically decreasing in $\beta$.

So

$$\min \mu = 1/(1+\beta)\implies \{\alpha \geq 1, \beta >0\}  \tag {1}$$

but the situation $\{\alpha >0, \beta \geq 1\}$ permits all possible values of $\mu$ (in $(0,1)$).

In other words by restricting the mean to lie in the interval $[1/(1+\beta),\, 1)$ we can guarantee that we will have $\{\alpha \geq 1, \beta >0\}$. But there is no restriction on the mean that will guarantee us that $\{\alpha >0, \beta \geq 1\}$.

So we should turn to the variance, which is

$$\sigma^2 = \frac {\alpha \beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2(\alpha + \beta +1)}$$

It is not difficult to determine that no restriction on the range of the variance can guarantee that we will have $\{\alpha >0, \beta \geq 1\}$.

So :

If we impose the restriction $\mu \geq  1/(1+\beta)$, then we will certainly have $\{\alpha \geq 1, \beta >0\}$, i.e. "not both parameters smaller than unity".

But this in a sense is a partial result, since there is also the other way in which "not both parameters are smaller than unity". In other words, this approach imposes the additional restriction that only $\beta$ is allowed to be smaller than unity. It is therefore *incompatible* with  Beta distributions for which we *want* to be able to have $\alpha \leq 1$ (and $\beta >1$).

Comment: It's unclear what your answer is.  Could you more specifically describe the solution set?

Comment: @whuber Did some reworking.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not seeing it. In fact, looking at the last paragraph, you seem to say the solution set is *empty* ("incompatible").  A clear answer would provide usable criteria to determine exactly when any ordered pair $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is or is not the mean and variance of a Beta distribution whose parameters are not both less than one. Those criteria would be in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ alone.

Comment: @whuber Oh, I, on the other hand, see it very clearly, and it is a case of "directly enforce what you would want to indirectly impose". Let me see if I can salvage this in some way.